# add tuple to a list without using pl list library in Prolog

Tags: prolog

this showName query will gives set of names:

```
?- showName(SName,Fname).
SName = 'McBrien',
FName = 'Alex' ;
SName = 'Gardner',
FName = 'Daniel' ;
SName = 'Phillips',
FName = 'Abbas' ;
SName = 'Pietzuch',
FName = 'Paul'  

and so on as I keep pressing ; it will gives more names.
```

I need write another function called

```
nameList (List). %which will put all names by query showName into List as a tuple
                  ((SName1,FName1),(SName2,FName2), ... )
```

I want try it without using Prolog library(list).
Thanks..

Comment: You can append all the names in the list as you find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your facts database is something like

```
person('Alex', 'McBrien', male).
person('Daniel', 'Gardner', male).
person('Abbas', 'Phillips', male).
person('Paul', 'Pietzuch', male).
```

without duplicates, you can do it without using `findall/3` by means of an accumulator, although with extra computational cost. You have to add an item to the accumulator only if its not already a member of it:

```
nameList(List):-
  nameList([], List).

nameList(IList, List):-
  (
   call(person(FName, SName, _)),
   \+ (member((SName, FName), IList))
  )-> nameList([(SName, FName)|IList], List) ; List=IList.
```

Procedure `nameList/1` just calls `nameList/2` with an empty accumulator.
Then procedure `nameList/2` will call every person from the facts database and check whether the person is in the accumulator list. If it finds one such person then it recursively calls itself adding this person to the accumulator. If it does not find any person not in the input list then it unifies this accumulator with the output List of persons.

Comment: Thanks this is shows details quite much , I want to understand prolog by this kind of data structure .. recursively mind ,you know :) Thanks for CapelliC as well, his method is very good too!